# #pragma aux not working in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pragma

This code compile succesfully (in visual studio),but there are some warnings like

source.cpp(7): warning C4068: unknown pragma

warning C4081: expected 'identifier'; found 'string'

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma aux __my "_*"           \
       parm routine [eax edx]               \
       value struct struct caller [ ] \
       modify [eax edx];



int __pragma("__my")   test(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){

    return a * 1 + b * 2 + c * 3 + d * 4 + e * 5;
}

int main(){
    printf("test\n");
    int x = test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    printf("X is %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

It should change the calling convention, but nothing happend.

Comment: Really important thing to know about `#pragma`: this is a compiler specific extension. It may not be supported by your compiler, and if it isn't the compiler is **allowed to silently discard it**. That " unknown pragma" message is a kindness. It might be supported and work very, very differently than you expect it to if you're porting code from another tool chain. If you see any `pragma` in unfamiliar code, research the pragma and how your tool chain supports it before using the code.

Comment: I thought the warning was self explanatory. Visual Studio has no clue what #pragma aux is supposed to do, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: So, it is there another method to change calling convetion ?
I need it for hooking and i dont want to write naked function with own assembler.

Comment: The usual `__cdecl`, `__stdcall`, and `__fastcall` don't cover your usecase?

Comment: No, because i hook function, which has special calling convetion.